# SSO Login: Cookie scheme does not match in FireFox

Tags: firefox, cookies, single-sign-on, cross-site

I have a Webapp (HTML, JS, PHP) on an Amazon cloud server which is integrated in our companies network. Lets say the servers name is

dev-myapp.cloud.myentity.mycompany.com

This app is using the companies global SSO login by getting an oauth token from the SSO login page and then sending client, secret and callback (as usual). If Login is successful, the SSO login redirects to my callback (which in that case is my apps url above)

The SSO login creates many cookies in the browser. Most of them are flagged as secure but also some are not. For all of this cookies I now get an error

Cookie "xxx" will be soon treated as cross-site cookie against "path_to_any_of_my_sources" because the scheme does not match

I get this error for every script which is loaded (HTML, js, PHP, css) with FireFox.

The domain of the created cookies is

mycompany.com

so there should be no cross site at all.

What can I do to remove this hundreds of warnings, which makes debugging really annoying

If you need more information please let me know. Please understand I cannot provide you with real data from my company.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to fix this same problem by clearing my cookies in the browser.

Comment: I already cleared everything a couple of time. But it looks like the actual version of FF has more problems. It is also not refreshing files from disc even if you disable the cache on open developer tools. Its anoying